# Launch Desktop Application Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webkit, node-webkit

So today, Google announced a desktop app launcher for its Google Drive service: http://googledrive.blogspot.ca/2014/11/launch-desktop-applications-from-google.html.

Any ideas on how they implemented this?  I'd like to do the same for a personal project.  I know there's a way in node-webkit to do something like this, but if this ever becomes a native capability within Chrome browser...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a chrome application launch local program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661827/can-a-chrome-application-launch-local-program)

Answer (score 0):

To quote the announcement:

> To get started, install the latest version of the Drive app for Mac or PC (version 1.18) ...

They are using a native app (not a Chrome app) to provide the functionality. As such, they can do whatever they want.

You can replicate this with a [Native Host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging) + extension approach.