# Using PPAPI to launch client applications e.g. Microsoft Word

Tags: javascript, html, npapi, ppapi

I am very new at PPAPI. I have already written a plugin to launch client's applications e.g. Word in my web based application using NPAPI (using a Java applet). Now I want to do that using PPAPI. Any chances?

Thanks
Reza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PPAPI is not a solution for what you are trying to do. You should look at Native Messaging (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661827/can-a-chrome-application-launch-local-program) for example).

Comment: To my understanding Native Messaging allows connecting Chrome extension or apps to a native application. In my case, it is a normal web application not a Chrome app. Do you still think it is possible? thanks.

Comment: It's possible, just annoying, to talk from a web page to a native message host application.  You basically use messaging to talk from the web page to the extension content script, then from the content script to the background script and from the background script to the host.

You might be able to bypass the content script and talk directly to the background script if you whitelist the specific domain for messaging purposes in the extension, otherwise you'll have to use cross-window messaging.  Anyway, it can be done; FireBreath2 does it